# Not able to create an EMAIL MESSAGE using SSJS in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, emailmessage

I am trying to find a way to create an email with a click from the browser using Javascript client side & server side ( AJAX ), but now having issues with SSJS, I tried to retrieve the id of the folder I want to create the email in but now success..

The [script](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_emailAdd.html) I am using is from the documentation, as I said the only thing I changed is the category id ( put the folder id, I suppose its right )

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1");
try {
  var newMail = {
    CustomerKey : "test_email_key",
    Name : "Test Taoufiq Email",
    CategoryID : "269685",
    HTMLBody : "<b>This is a test email</b>",
    TextBody : "This is a test email",
    Subject : "Test Email Subject",
    IsActive : "true",
    IsHTMLPaste : "true",
    Status : "active",
    EmailType : "HTML",
    CharacterSet : "US-ASCII",
    HasDynamicSubjectLine : "false"
};
  
var myEmail = Email.Add(newMail);

} catch (ex) {
        Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
        Variable.SetValue("@Result", Stringify(ex));  //sets above ampscript variable
    }
  
</script>
```

The error I am getting is a general one : ***Error Adding Email*** nothing more

Anyone have an idea and got the chance to work on this before ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Email functions are actually connected to the Classic Emails from Email Studio, not Content Builder - making these functions pretty much unusable now that Classic has been sunset. These functions as well as WSProxy are attached to the SOAP Objects and the only way to access Content Builder is via the REST API.

This is likely why you are receiving that error and why this is not working.

Comment: there was an error, Actually I did not specify the ctegory id and it worked but this isn't useful anyways, content is being created successfuly because I don't get any error ( when I reexecute scriot, I get error because of duplicated name ), but it is in the CLASSIC content that isn't accessible now anyways .. But I can't create an email message using the REST API, from what I have seen, so does that mean there is no solution ?

Comment: yes, it is possible to create content via REST API

Comment: If its just the email, yes you can use the POST `asset/v1/content/assets` endpoint. If you mean you want to send an email, you can use the undocumented POST `messaging/v1/rest` group of endpoints to find the one that best suits your needs.